# Create new column in R dataframe based on results from 3 other columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe containing Id and scan results. 1 denoted if a result not seen on a scan. 2 if a result seen and no vector if scan not completed.

I wish to create one column at the end of the dataframe which checks all 3 columns and returns a "2" if result ever seen in any of the 3 scans. "1" if result not seen on a scan and no vector if patient never had a scan completed on any three modalities.

- Basically result "2" is the dominant vector - if it appears in dataframe row I want it to shown in new column
- if "2" not present then if "1" present that needs to appear in new column
- if no result in any column then, no result or NA to appear

I have tried doing this in Excel and R. I would prefer to use R as I am learning this at the moment and want to continue learning new uses.

I have tried using

```
library(tidyverse)
USS_reports %>%
   mutate((filter(USSfluid=2 | CTfluid=2 | MRIfluid=2))

id  USSFluid    CTfluid MRIfluid
1       1             1        1
2       1                      1    
3       1             1        1
4       1             1 
5       1             1 
6       1             1 
7       1       
8                     1     
9       1       
10                    1       2 
11      1             2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you want to give the highest value precedence, you could just use `apply` to take the `max` value per row (`MARGIN = 1`) of the dataframe excluding the first id column (`[,-1]`):

```
USS_reports %>% mutate(summary = apply(USS_reports[,-1], MARGIN = 1, 
FUN = function(row)max(row, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%  
mutate(summary = ifelse(summary == -Inf, NA, summary))
```

Note that the second mutate is needed to replace the -Inf values that are returned by max when all cols are NA with NA. For this to work, your df needs to be numeric though. If not, you would first have to do

```
USS_reports[] <- lapply(USS_reports, as.numeric)
```

(btw, if you want to test for equality in your code above, you have to use == instead of = )

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that on first glance is less straightforward, but is intended to scale for more than these 3 columns you're checking. I `gather`ed the dataframe into a long format, made a single string for each ID of all the results, then used a `case_when` to check for each of the possibilities: there's a result with a 2, there's a result with a 1, or there's no result. I like `case_when` to avoid lots of `ifelse`s nested inside each other.

I also added a test case for when there's no result, just to make sure that possibility comes out okay too.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
# test case with no results
    bind_rows(tibble(id = 12)) %>%
    gather(key = scan, value = result, -id) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(all_str = paste(result, collapse = ",")) %>%
    mutate(overall = case_when(
        str_detect(all_str, "2") ~ "2",
        str_detect(all_str, "1") ~ "1",
        T ~ "no result"
    ))

#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#>       id all_str  overall  
#>    <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    
#>  1    1. 1,1,1    1        
#>  2    2. 1,1,NA   1        
#>  3    3. 1,1,1    1        
#>  4    4. 1,1,NA   1        
#>  5    5. 1,1,NA   1        
#>  6    6. 1,1,NA   1        
#>  7    7. 1,NA,NA  1        
#>  8    8. 1,NA,NA  1        
#>  9    9. 1,NA,NA  1        
#> 10   10. 1,2,NA   2        
#> 11   11. 1,2,NA   2        
#> 12   12. NA,NA,NA no result
```

Created on 2018-04-27 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and help. I have been struggling with this for days!Works perfectly. Thank you